# Laravel DB::raw() not executing query but manual execute works

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am running this query

```
$query = "update my_cloud set full_dir_url = replace(full_dir_url, '$findWhat', '$replaceWith') where full_dir_url like '$findWhat/%' or where full_dir_url = '$findWhat' ";
DB::raw($query);
echo $query;
```

Output of `echo $query` is

> update my_cloud set full_dir_url = replace(full_dir_url, '/1st Year/Slide', '/1st Year/Slides') where full_dir_url like '/1st Year/Slide/%' or where full_dir_url = '/1st Year/Slide'

When I run this query in phpmyadmin sql editor, data is updated as expected.

But that `DB::raw($query)` doesn't update any data. No error log either.

Answer (score 3):

`DB::raw` doesn't run a query, it wraps the string in an object so that Laravel knows that it should not escape the contents.

Instead you can use the [`DB::update`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/ConnectionInterface.html#method_update) function:

```
$query = "update my_cloud set full_dir_url = replace(full_dir_url, '$findWhat', '$replaceWith') where full_dir_url like '$findWhat/%' or where full_dir_url = '$findWhat' ";
DB::update(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

**Issue 1:** `DB::raw` shouldn't work as Renée said. `DB::statement` or `DB::update` both worked for me.

**Issue 2** `or where full_dir_url='$findWhat'` -this clause is wrong. I removed `where` from `or where` and that worked.